# Birthdays migrate to Profile2

Tags: 7, views, users

guys.

I've this issue, i did migrate a user list from csv file with Migrate module to Profile2. I'd use one only value for the import with the format dd/mm/Y.  All was fine, but at the end the birthdays fields are empty.

What is the right way to import (update) my user birthdays.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I believe (most) dates in Drupal are simply stored as 11 digit integers. The `format` you refer to is only whats displayed on the page. Your migration probably just needs to be moving the integer date data by simply moving the data from your source csv column into your new profile2 Drupal Field:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('csv_birthday_column', 'new_profile2_birthday_field');
```

Then you just use a Profile2 `Manage Display` under the Field UI to setup how you want it to look on the page such as `d/m/Y`.

**EDIT:**

If your CSV has for example "04/15/2013" as a date for a piece of content you could use PHP `strtotime()` in a Migration class `prepareRow()` function to get an integer value to save in Drupal.